# How to code Mysql DATE_FORMAT in cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

My Code in Mysql:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT( created , '%Y') from item;`

How do you code in CakePHP?

Answer (score 2):

The `func()` method can be used here.
Considering that you would be writing the query in the Item model, following code snippet can be useful:

```
    $query = $this->find();
    $createdYear = $query->func()->date_format([
        'created' => 'identifier',
        "'%Y'" => 'literal'
    ]);
    $query->select(['id','createdYear'=>$createdYear]);
    $result = $query->all();
```

Cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

Please code `'date_format("%Y-%m-%d", created)'` in `fields`.
`"%Y-%m-%d"` is date format.
`created` is column name.

```
$this->Item->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'date_format("%Y-%m-%d", created)',
    )
));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on [so]. Please explain a little bit what is going on. Thank you.